# MySql, set ranking of rows on each day

Tags: mysql, sql

The data in the table will be add every day of a crawler. So the first entry should be ranked as no.1 each day. But because the crawler can crawler the product 2x time. It is show that the next row has the same name. If that's true then it need to have the same ranking as the previous row.

This is what i have traid so far:

```
    SELECT a.product_ranking_id, a.Productinfo, a.Date, 
    (
      SELECT index(Productinfo)
      From ProductRanking as b
      Where a.Date = b.Date
    ) as Rank
    From ProductRanking as a
```

End Results

```
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
| Table:  ProductRanking |              |            |      |
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
| product_ranking_id     | Productinfo  | Date       | Rank |
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
|                        | product 1    | 01-01-2018 | 1    |
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
|                        | product 1    | 01-01-2018 | 1    |
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
|                        | product 2    | 01-01-2018 | 2    |
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
|                        | product 3    | 01-01-2018 | 3    |
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
|                        | product 445  | 01-01-2018 | 4    |
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
|                        | product 3    | 02-01-2018 | 1    |
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
|                        | product 89   | 02-01-2018 | 2    |
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
|                        | product 89   | 02-01-2018 | 2    |
+------------------------+--------------+------------+------+
```

Solution:

With help of Gordon Linoff i found a solution. That's why i mark his answer.
Always welcome if it can be better..

```
SELECT *,(@i := if(a.Productinfo != b.Productinfo, 
                if(a.date = b.date, @i + 1,@i := 1),   @i)   ) as Rank
From
    productrank as a
    left join productrank as b on b.product_ranking_id = a.product_ranking_id -1
    Cross join (SELECT @i := 1) params
;
```

Comment: add expected output

Comment: What is `index(Product info)`?

Comment: @JayShankarGupta  that's already in there end results

Comment: @GordonLinoff my idea was get the index row number of a group. But that something that i only can be done with programming language i see that doesn't work for mysql..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select pr.*,
       (@rn := if(@pd = concat_ws(' ', productinfo, date), @rn + 1,
                  if(@pd := concat_ws(' ', productinfo, date), 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rank
from (select pr.*
      from ProductRanking pr
      order by Productinfo, Date
     ) pr cross join
     (select @pd := '', @rn := 0) params;
```

In older versions of MySQL the subquery is not necessary.  You can `order by` in the outer query.

EDIT:

Assuming `product_ranking_id` contains a sequential id:

```
select pr.*,
       (@rn := if(@p = productinfo, @rn + 1,
                  if(@p := productinfo, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rank
from (select pr.*
      from ProductRanking pr
      order by Productinfo, product_ranking_id
     ) pr cross join
     (select @p := '', @rn := 0) params;
```

Comment: i traid it.. but all get the ranking of no.1 not like the results table

Comment: @FT . . . Are you sure the dates are exactly the same with no time component?  Also, there was a typo in the first version, using `@pr` in the expressions but `@pd` for initialization.

Comment: I traid the new version...  but i get these results... product1 rank1, product1 rank2, product 2 rank1, product3 rank1, product3 rank2..  this looks in the good direction .. but it need to switch 180 degree.. it should be:
product1 rank1, product1 rank1, product2 rank2, product 3 rank3, product3 rank3 etc..